# Removing "Choose forum field" from forum nodes content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

can I remove the "Choose forum dropdown field" from my forum nodes content types ?

I have only 1 forum and there is only 1 choice I would like my users not have to select it as additional step.

If there is not any option to remove it I would like to know how I can submit the form with that value.

I've tried to hide it: `$form['taxonomy']['#type'] = 'hidden';`

But it doesn't work because it is required, and I need to specify it if I want the new post added to the forum... I actually need to submit a default value if I want to hide it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `#required` to `FALSE`, `#type` to `'value'`, and `#value` to the value you find in `#default_value`.
Doing so, the user will not see any selector, but the form submission handler will get a value.

Answer (score 1):

Use hook_form_alter and supply a hardcoded value and default value (what the value would be if they picked it), set #required to no. That should work.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6

Comment: yeah I'm using hook_form_alter, I know how to set required to no, but I don't know how to exactly hardcode it. thanks

Comment: $form['element']['#default_value'] = 'term'; $form['element']['#value'] = 'term'; something like that. Or, it might want a TID. Inspect your form to be sure. The option values in the drop down will be your answer.